# can't get Ajax to work with a keyed api

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to use the [NYT api](http://developer.nytimes.com/page) to work, but I keep getting different errors. I tried using this

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/all/.json?api-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xx:xxxxxxxxxx&callback=?",
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    success:function(json){
       alert("Success");
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("Error");
    },
});
```

When i run this I get

```
      Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I know of the implications making cross domain requests, but i'm not sure if i'm eveing doing this right

Comment: it looks like an invalid URL. nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: It looks like it wants your api-key in the format of `&api-key={xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx}?callback` not `?api-key`

Comment: @gdoron what about his URL looks invalid? Other than the ? instead of the & in front of the api-key, this is the proper way to construct the URI request for the NYT API. Check the API out that he linked.

Comment: I used their [api request tool](http://prototype.nytimes.com/gst/apitool/index.html?api_id=10&request_id=0&source=all&section=all&time-period=&limit=&offset=&resp_format=json&perform_request=Make+Request&use_pp=on) and this is what it says i should use `http://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/all/.json?api-key=####`, and when i use that uri with my key, it works find, its only when i put it in my script it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

All you're missing is changing `.json` to `.jsonp` in the url.

Your code is correct, but if you look at the response returned, you'll notice it's not actually a jsonp response; it's just a regular json payload.

Adding the callback parameter doesn't cause the NYT APIs to automatically return jsonp. If you want jsonp, use the `.jsonp` format and provide the callback param.

Answer (score 0):

From ([RFC 1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), Dec. '94) :

> Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters
>   "$-_.+!*'()," [not including the quotes - ed], and reserved characters
>   used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.

So you need either to encode uri manually before making ajax call or pass parameters by `'data'` object:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/all/.json",
    data: {"api-key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xx:xxxxxxxxxx"},
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    success:function(json){
      alert("Success");
    },
    error:function(){
       alert("Error");
    },
});
```

Also I am not specifiying '`callback=?`' parameter , because jquery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will send it automatically, if `dataType` is `jsonp`.

Comment: @alme1304 can you provide a `nytimes api`'s link, where it is mentioned about supporting jsonp?

Comment: is there another way to do cross-domain?

Comment: @alme1304 if jsonp is not supported by api, then only way is from server-side script.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem my specifying jsonp in my request url:

`http://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/all/.jsonp?limit=10&api-key={my key}`

And then when calling the method only specifying `dataType: 'jsonp'` and not `jsonp: 'jsonp'` or anything like that.